# Problems when converting from imp to importlib in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-importlib

I've made a Python application which can load plugins. These plugins are loaded based on a name and path.

I am currently using

```
pluginModule = imp.load_source(pluginModuleName,  pluginModulePath)
```

and then getting a class instance in the module this way

```
# Load the module class and initialize it.
if hasattr(pluginModule, pluginClassName):
  try:
    pluginClassInst = getattr(pluginModule, pluginClassName)()
  except Exception as e:
    errorMsg = ('In plugin module [{}], {}'.format(os.path.basename(pluginModulePath), e))
    exceptionTracePrint(self._log)
    self._log.error(errorMsg)
    continue
```

Since the imp lib is deprecated I want to use importlib. And the only similar method of getting my class instance was to use

```
pluginModule = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(pluginModuleName, pluginModulePath).load_module()
```

The weird thing here is that (I am using pyCharm as IDE). when I run my code in debugging mode the above command works fine and I get my class instance. however running the code normally gives me the following error.

```
pluginModule = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(pluginModuleName, pluginModulePath).load_module()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'machinery'
```

Why is there a difference between run and debug.
Is there an alternative way of doing what I want.

Ive also tried

```
pluginModuleTmp = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(pluginModuleName, pluginModulePath)
```

Which also gives me the correct data however I cannot load the module this way or at least I do not know how

Regards
Anders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Apparently in debug mode a lot more modules are imported behind my back. I fixed it by adding the import.

```
import importlib.machinery
```

Regards
Anders